# Environment doesn't exist error gym_anytrading

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am trying to create the environment using gym_anything and I got an error that the environment doesn't exist.

```
import gym
import gym_anytrading
#passing the data and creating our environment
env = gym.make('stocks-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(5,100), window_size=5)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b826e9775e38> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #passing the data and creating our environment
----> 2 env = gym.make('stocks-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(5,100), window_size=5)
      3 
      4 
      5 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in _check_name_exists(ns, name)
    210     suggestion_msg = f"Did you mean: `{suggestion[0]}`?" if suggestion else ""
    211 
--> 212     raise error.NameNotFound(
    213         f"Environment {name} doesn't exist{namespace_msg}. {suggestion_msg}"
    214     )

NameNotFound: Environment stocks doesn't exist.
```

Comment: The [example on the `gym_anytrading` github page](https://github.com/AminHP/gym-anytrading#create-an-environment) uses `gymnasium` instead of `gym`, have you tried changing this?